# SQL query with grouping and join into LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq, join, count

I know that there are a lot of related topics in this site but I just cannot find something which works for me. I'm sorry if it looks too much like a duplicate. Anyway, my problem is that I am trying to convert the following SQL query into LINQ but nothing I tried so far seemed to work.
The query is:

```
select top(10) a.AddressText, t.Name, count(e.FirstName) as [EmployeesCount]
from Addresses a
join Employees e
on a.AddressID = e.AddressID
join Towns t
on a.TownID = t.TownID
group by a.AddressText, t.Name
order by [EmployeesCount] desc, t.Name asc
```

What I got so far is:

```
SoftUniEntities context = new SoftUniEntities();

var addresses = from a in context.Addresses.Take(10) join e in context.Employees on a.AddressID equals e.AddressID 
join t in context.Towns on a.TownID equals t.TownID into addressesWithTownsAndEmployees
orderby addressesWithTownsAndEmployees.Count() descending, a.Town.Name ascending 
select new { Address = a.AddressText, TownName = a.Town.Name, EmployeesCount = addressesWithTownsAndEmployees.Count() };
```

The problem is with the count. The result for it is incorrect and it's perfectly normal because I know I've messed up the count selection.

Comment: Please show us, what you've tried so far, and where the problems occurred.

Comment: I edited my post with my current linq query

Answer (score 0):

After thinking more about how to do it in LINQ without relating it too much with sql I came up with this far less complex LINQ query:

```
var addresses = (from a in context.Addresses 
orderby a.Employees.Count descending, a.Town.Name ascending
select new { Address = a.AddressText, TownName = a.Town.Name,
EmployeesCount = a.Employees.Count }).Take(10).ToList();
```